# Basic Array Initialization Returning Error

Tags: c++

The starred lines below are throwing back the following error:

`error: scalar object 'paper' requires one element in initializer`

Any idea what might be causing this? This seems like a relatively straightforward initialization.

```
int main(){

    double paper [] = {8.0, 11.0};//***
    double box [] = {6.0, 10.0};//***

    paperFold pf;
    cout << pf.numFolds(paper,box) << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: C or C++? They are different languages. Don't tag both. Compiler?

Comment: What's `paperFold`? Anyway, array code seems fine, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you're compiling that code and not something else in a file with the same name, and that you haven't forgotten to save? I've lost count of how many times I've made those mistakes.

Comment: C++, and I'm compiling with g++.

Comment: Just a class - solving some problems on TopCoder to knock off some C++ rust. You can find more here : https://arena.topcoder.com/#/u/practiceCode/1285/1721/1846/1/1285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line :

```
double paper [] = {8.0, 11.0};
```

is perfectly correct either in C or in C++, for any versions I can remember.

But compilers can be disturbed by other errors in the stream.

This code is fine in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double paper [] = { 8.0, 11.0 }; //***

    std::cout << paper[0] << " - " << paper[1] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As is this one in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double paper [] = { 8.0, 11.0 }; //***

    printf("%f - %f\n", paper[0], paper[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now sure how, but it appears it was being caused by eclipse (or more likely, my own dumb error because I'm unfamiliar with the IDE). Deleted the project, recreated/pasted in exact code, and compiled fine.

Answer (score 1):

The error message complains that you are trying to initializing a *scalar* object `paper` with multiple initializers.
i.e. something like this:

```
double paper = {8.0, 11.0};
```

But obviously `paper` is an *aggregate* type in the code you posted which shouldn't produce that error. So, it means you haven't posted
the code that produced the error or simply failed to *save* the source file?

Comment: Swapped over to using an IDE (eclipse) as I'm running through a large amount of practice problems to knock off some rust - appears that is causing the error. Successfully compiled at the command line, however.